# C# - Enabling multiple textboxes in a loop

Tags: c#, wpf, loops, textbox

I'm writing a WPF program, and it involves someone typing in a number, and enabling a corresponding number of text boxes. Currently I have a system that checks every single text box such as

```
private void navnumbox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (Int32.Parse(navnumbox.Text) > 0)
        {
            One.IsEnabled = true;
        }

        if (Int32.Parse(navnumbox.Text) > 1)
        {
            Two.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to put this into a loop, and I'm think that I may need to store One and Two in an array, but I have tried but I don't know how to access them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try something like this (I wasn't able to test it sorry).

```
private void navnumbox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var textBoxesMap = new Dictionary<int,TextBox>()
    {
        {1, One},
        {2, Two}
        // etc
    };

    try
    {
        int number = int.Parse(navnumbox.Text)
        foreach(var item in textBoxesMap)
        {
            if(item.Key <= number)
            {
                item.Value.IsEnabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you can obviously place the map somewhere else. An alternative (and better) approach to this would be to use XAML - there is another answer on this question that demonstrates how to do so.

Comment: A XAML solution with value converters and bindings would be much better. WPF is very hard to use if you insist on fighting against it instead of working with it.

Comment: I agree there is better approaches to the problem using XAML, fact is though that many developers treat WPF as if it were win forms. I don't know if I agree that WPF is "very hard to use" if you don't embrace XAML.

Comment: @clean_coding You've done serious WPF projects without data binding or templates? How many?

Comment: You misunderstand, I would not make a "serious WPF project" without using XAML and data binding, or even without using MVVM. But I do know that a lot of developers actually just use it as if it were win forms - which is just what I meant. I do not mean to discourage people from using XAML at all, just when there are simple questions like the one from OP, usually it's easier to help them moving on in what they already know - I should've mentioned in my answer that the XAML approach would be better. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the better approach is to use Converter for Visibility property of the TextBoxes One and Two by ElementBinding to the navnumbox Path=Text.

I your case you will need separate converters for TextBox.Enable for TextBoxes One and Two.

Here XAML for the Window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpfApplication2="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <wpfApplication2:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter"></wpfApplication2:MyConverter>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox x:Name="MyText"></TextBox>
            <TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=MyText, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here implementation of the Converter for TexBox "One"

```
public class MyConverter
        : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string myValue = value as string;
            int result = 0;
            if (myValue != null)
            {
                int.TryParse(myValue,out result);
            }

            return result > 0;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            // not relevant for your application
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```